# Falha de segmentação: Imagem do núcleo gravada

Tags: c, array, memória, falha-de-segmentação

Fiz um código em C para encontrar o menor valor e posição do mesmo em um vetor x[N]. Toda vez que compilo o programa pelo terminal (Linux), o mesmo acusa a seguinte mensagem:

> Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Eu utilizei o mesmo código no Windows e o programa foi executado com êxito.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int N, i, menor, posicao,  x[N];

scanf("%d",&N);

i=0;

for(i;i<N;i++) scanf("%d",&x[i]);

menor = x[0];
posicao = 0;

for(i;i<N;i++){ 
    if(menor > x[i]){
        menor = x[i];
        posicao = i;
    } 
}   
printf("Menor valor: %d", menor);
printf("Posicao: %d", posicao);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

O principal motivo é que está criando um vetor com uma quantidade aleatória de posições, é o que estiver na memória naquele momento, e isto fará estourar a memória na maioria das vezes, mas não em todas.

O que provavelmente queria é declarar o vetor depois de perguntar quantas posições seriam (conforme fiz no código), aí você reserva na memória o espaço para a quantidade digitada, deixa de pegar um valor arbitrário.

Nada tem a ver com o sistema operacional e sim com o lixo de memória que tem naquele momento da execução no local que foi alocado para sua sua aplicação. Pode eventualmente até repetir o mesmo valor, mas é só coincidência.

Este erro provavelmente tem a ver com a mania das pessoas querem ensinar C como era na década de 70, ou como é em Pascal. Por isso eu sou crítico de quase todos os cursos de programação que tem por aí, não ensinam como se programa na real.

O código ainda não toma alguns cuidados, mas para exercício está bom. Eu dei uma melhorada na organização para ficar mais legível e mais eficiência (um laço resolve a questão, não precisa pedir os dados e depois varrer todo o vetor para achar a informação desejada).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int x[n];
    int menor = INT_MAX;
    int posicao = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        if (x[i] < menor) {
            menor = x[i];
            posicao = i;
        } 
    }   
    printf("Menor valor: %d Posicao: %d", menor, posicao);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yoYKEg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nyhrkbtr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Allocation.c).

Comment: Maniero, qual é o problema com o meu código?? Um vez que foi executado no Windows e não foi executado no Linux!!!!

Comment: Acabei de explicar, não tem nada a ver com sistema operacional, é virtualmente aleatório, podenendo até mesmo repetir a mesma situação várias vezes.

Comment: Desculpa!! Prestei atenção logo no seu código e não sua explicação acima. Sou novato nessa comunidade!!!

Answer (score 1):

Resposta curta: você está usando N para criar a matriz x[N] antes que o valor de N seja definido, então ele é aleatório (mas em geral será zero).

Declare x[N] depois do scanf(). Em C99 é permitido declarar variáveis depois do início da função.